# JavaScript calculator - Unable to understand few lines in code

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in coding and while following YouTube channel WebDevSimplified, I came across below JS code for making a calculator. In the below code, I am not able to understand, how `currentOperand` and `previousOperand` are being used without defining? It looks like `currentOperand` is referencing to `currentOperandTextElement` and `previousOperand` to `previousOperandTextElement`, However its not defined anywhere in code. below is the link for GitHub repo

**https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Vanilla-JavaScript-Calculator/blob/master/script.js**

Request you all to help me understand. Thank you so much.

```js
    class Calculator {
      constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
        this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
        this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
        this.clear()
      }
    
      clear() {
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
      }
    
      delete() {
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
      }
    
      appendNumber(number) {
        if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
      }
    
      chooseOperation(operation) {
        if (this.currentOperand === '') return
        if (this.previousOperand !== '') {
          this.compute()
        }
        this.operation = operation
        this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
        this.currentOperand = ''
      }
    
      compute() {
        let computation
        const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
        const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
        if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return
        switch (this.operation) {
          case '+':
            computation = prev + current
            break
          case '-':
            computation = prev - current
            break
          case '*':
            computation = prev * current
            break
          case '÷':
            computation = prev / current
            break
          default:
            return
        }
        this.currentOperand = computation
        this.operation = undefined
        this.previousOperand = ''
      }
    
      getDisplayNumber(number) {
        const stringNumber = number.toString()
        const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
        const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1]
        let integerDisplay
        if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
          integerDisplay = ''
        } else {
          integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
        }
        if (decimalDigits != null) {
          return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
        } else {
          return integerDisplay
        }
      }
    
      updateDisplay() {
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText =
          this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
        if (this.operation != null) {
          this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText =
            `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`
        } else {
          this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = ''
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
    const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
    const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
    const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
    const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
    const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
    const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')
    
    const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)
    
    numberButtons.forEach(button => {
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
      })
    })
    
    operationButtons.forEach(button => {
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
      })
    })
    
    equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
      calculator.compute()
      calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
    
    allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
      calculator.clear()
      calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
    
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
      calculator.delete()
      calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
```

Comment: I don't understand where your confusion lies. There are several places where `this.currentOperand` and `this.previousOperand` are assigned values.

Comment: They are defined in the parameters to the constructor (all over the place). I'd imagine this is an exercise in learning to declare variables at the top of your code and possible variable scope.

Comment: They are defined as DOM nodes halfway down: `const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')` and 
    `const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')`

Comment: Honestly this looks more like a homework assignment. Don't cheat yourself.

Comment: Apologies everyone for asking the silly question. I will be careful next time. Thanks for your response

Comment: @MattU I thought it should have been defined as variable, hence I was getting confused. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentOperand` and `previousOperand` are dynamically being created as fields on the class `Calculator`. Since both of them were not defined in the constructor, their initial value is `undefined`.

For example, as operations are performed on the calculator by `appendNumber`, `this.currentOperand` is assigned a value, which can be used later by `chooseOperation()` and `compute()`.